# Explaining That there is no nontrivial ring homomorphism between Z and nZ

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

My instructor wrote in his notes the following example:

"As groups (Z,+) and (nZ,+) are isomorphic.  As rings is there any nontrivial homomorphism $\phi$: Z->nZ?

The answer is no and he gives the following justification which I don't quite understand:

Consider a homomorphism $\phi$: Z->nZ with n>1
$1^2=1$ so $\phi(1^2)$=$\phi(1)$
So $\phi(1)$ satisfies $x^2=x$ and this has two solutions 0, and 1 hence $\phi(1)=0$

So what I don't understand is 1. Why did he use the example with $1^2$?  and how did he eliminate the possibility that 0 cannot be $\phi(1)$?

It would be great if you can explain this in detail for someone new to the concept of rings.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to note here that it's typical to *define* rings so that they are required to have an identity, and to define ring homomorphisms as homomorphisms which preserve this identity (in addition to the operations). The argument here shows that for "nice" rings like $\mathbb{Z}$ (or any other integral domain), we're not leaving out anything interesting. Sometimes to emphasize that this requirement is *not* there, rings which may not have an identity are called "rngs" (a ring without the i!).

Answer (score 3):

The argument shows that $\phi(1)\in n\mathbb Z$ satisfies $\phi(1)=\phi(1)^2$. The only element in $n\mathbb Z$ (for $n>1$) that is equal to its square is $0$. So $\phi(1)=0$.

But then
$$
\phi(k)=\phi(1+\cdots+1)=k\,\phi(1)=k\cdot0=0.
$$
So $\phi=0$, i.e. there is no nontrivial ring homomorphism between $\mathbb Z$ and $n\mathbb Z$.